# Optimizing Exponential curve fit in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit an exponential curve on my data using python `scipy` libray `curve_fit` function:

```
def model_func(x, a, k, b):
    return a * np.exp(k*x) + b
```

I expect the nature of fit to be negative exponential. As expected I  got the negative exponential curve but I am not sure whether the selected parameters `a, k, b` are optimized. I see some of the data as highlighted in the attached picture are not considered by the fitted curve.
[image]

**The code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# define the exponential function
def model_func(x, a, k, b):
    return a * np.exp(k*x) + b

# data
x = np.array([0.63240641, 0.71793968, 0.15350684, 2.14915722, 0.45236403,
       0.48638794, 0.74329402, 0.38316468, 0.96695818, 0.80566539,
       1.23177184, 0.41871701, 0.44817087, 1.43515037, 0.23249725,
       0.70730449, 0.23058788, 0.55216397, 0.72072229, 0.70620709,
       1.51952697, 0.96881724, 0.40695986])
y = np.array([ 8.,  6., 10.,  5., 10., 12.,  6.,  8.,  7.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,
        6.,  8.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  6., 12.])

# curve fit
p0 = (1.,1.e-5,1.) # starting search coeffs

opt, pcov = curve_fit(model_func, x, y, p0)
a, k, b = opt

# test result
x2 = np.linspace(0.05,2.5, 10000)
y2 = model_func(x2, a, k, b)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (3.5,3))

ax.plot(x2, y2,color = 'lime', label=r'$V = %.2f e^{%.2f \tau} %+.2f$' % (a,k,b))

ax.scatter(x, y, color = 'navy', alpha = 0.75)

plt.xlabel(r'$\tau$')
plt.ylabel('V')

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.125))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))

ax.legend(frameon = False, markerscale = 0.2)
sns.despine(right = True)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

**Desired result:**

Can you please help me optimizing the coefficients `a,k,b` and include the highlighted data points in the curve fit also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the fit is fine. If you would draw an exponential through of close to those two outliers, the residual error of the points to the left would be very large, causing a bad fit.

Comment: I'd also say that there is nothing wrong with that fit. If at all, one would see if outliers should be considered even less ( assuming an underlying non-Gaussian error distribution or some additional random events) by using a different [loss function](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html)

Comment: Thank you both @ `9769953` and `mikuszefski` .... Is it also possible to fit another model like `y = (a/x) + c` to these data? How would I be sure that the above model is appropriate not others? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated..